# Why are my data directories so large when sharding a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, sharding

I'm playing with sharding a collection in MongoDB and have created some scripts to set up replica sets, add them to shards, then add these shards to my primary `mongos` process.

I generate data with a very stupid Python script:

```
import json

def gen_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(100000*33):
            d = {"Hello": i, "World" : 99999-i}
            json.dump(d, f)
            f.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_data("my_data.json")
```

I created four shards (`a, b, c, d`) with three repl sets per shard (`0, 1, 2`). The data directories are called `a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, c0, c1, c2, d0, d1, d2`.

I make chunk sizes 100M after enabling sharding of my collection, `"hello.world"`. I import the data, index on `'_id'`, then wait for migration.

After my balancer finishes running, I find that I have a nearly equal number of chunks in each shard, but the number of chunks doesn't make sense with respect to the data:

```
databases:
    {  "_id" : "hello",  "primary" : "a",  "partitioned" : true }
        hello.world
            shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
            unique: false
            balancing: true
            chunks:
                a   3
                b   3
                c   3
                d   2
//...
```

`my_data.json` is 118M, but when I check the size of my data directories, I'm quite surprised to find each of them much larger than the original data:

```
[erip@my_host shard_experiment]$ for s in {a..d}; do for n in {0..2}; do du -sh "$s$n"; done; done;
521M    a0
420M    a1
421M    a2
344M    b0
343M    b1
342M    b2
336M    c0
337M    c1
337M    c2
335M    d0
337M    d1
337M    d2
```

Why are my data directories so large? I use the `--smallfiles` when I set up my shard servers, yet I'm finding large overhead with such small imported documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `--smallfiles` option only applies to the MMAPv1 storage engine, it does not apply to the WiredTiger storage engine which is the default in MongoDB 3.2.

The MongoDB [Journal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) is likely using a considerable amount of your space, probably 300MB for each node. You can verify this by running something like:

```
find . -name "journal" -exec du -sh {} \;
```

Also, the [Replica Set Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) is probably also using a reasonable amount of space. You can check the oplog size being used by logging into the mongo shell for one of your replica sets and running `db.printReplicationInfo()`. You can reduce this by setting the oplogSize when you initially start the replica set for the first time.

With a very small amount of data as you have, the overhead is large, but as your data grows much larger this overhead will be only a small amount.

Chunk splits are done preemptively using a heuristic algorithm, so you will see splits happen before the chunks reach the maximum size.